# Adding an image without drag-and-drop in Xcode 10

Tags: xcode

I'd like to add some images to an image set in Xcode 10. However, I'm using Xcode 10 in full-screen mode, and each time I need to add an image, I have to carry Xcode 10 window into the main desktop, do the image hauling, and go back to fullscreen mode. Is there an easy way of doing it that does not involve drag-and-drop?

Comment: In the assets editor `+` > `Import...` (or right click > Import...)

Comment: Alright that works. Can you post this as an answer please?

Comment: Done. Glad that helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ways to import your images:

While in the assets editor

- Click on `+` > `Import...`

*or*

- Right click on the left panel > `Import...`

*or*

- `Editor` > `Add Assets` > `Import...`

---

Alternatively, you could split your fullscreen space by dragging a finder window so you have a file browser & xcode side by side and then drag & drop the assets